# Flatten an array of arrays in CPLEX OPL

Tags: cplex, opl

I have an array like:

```
[[101.2], [455.5], [676.1], [232.2], [444.4], [90.1], [280.2]]
```

How would I go about merging the separate inner arrays into one like:

```
[101.2, 455.5, 676.1, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
range r=1..7;

float v[r][1..1]=

[[101.2], [455.5], [676.1], [232.2], [444.4], [90.1], [280.2]];

float v2[i in r]=v[i][1];

execute
{
  writeln(v2);
}
```

gives

```
[101.2 455.5 676.1 232.2 444.4 90.1 280.2]
```

Comment: And in this scenario: `[[101.2, 455.5], [676.1, 232.2], [444.4, 90.1], [280.2, 125.1]]` to `[101.2 455.5 676.1 232.2 444.4 90.1 280.2 125.1]`

Answer (score 0):

for your second question:

```
range r=1..4;
range r2=1..2;
range r3=1..8;

float v[r][r2]=

[[101.2, 455.5], [676.1, 232.2], [444.4, 90.1], [280.2, 125.1]];

float v2[i in r3]=v[(i-1) div 2+1][(i-1) mod 2+1];

execute
{
  writeln(v2);
}
```

gives

```
[101.2 455.5 676.1 232.2 444.4 90.1 280.2 125.1]
```